# round off minutes to nearest number in (00,15,30,45) in python

Tags: python, datetime, logic

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from pytz import timezone
def select_scheduled_time():
 tz = timezone('UTC')
 Time_Now = datetime.now(tz)
 minutes = Time_Now.strftime("%M")
 print("Current Time =", minutes)
 print(Time_Now)
 if minutes not in ('00', '15', '30', '45'):
    mint = int(minutes)
    if (mint > 00 and mint < 15):
        mint = 15
    elif (mint > 15 and mint < 30):
        mint = 30
    elif (mint > 30 and mint < 45):
        mint = 45
    else:
        mint = 00
```

Want to find a logical answer for this so that i can avoid if statements. if the time is 9:10 then it should be rounded to 9:15. If time is 10:01 then also it should be 10:15.
Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `if` statements?

Comment: I thought it would be a cleaner code if I could come up with an arithmetic statement.

Comment: What is `timezone`? Does your solution work?

Comment: yes mine works too. Timezone is to get time according to eastern or western zone etc

Comment: I get a TypeError for `tz = timezone('UTC')` - `TypeError: timezone() argument 1 must be datetime.timedelta, not str`

Comment: i have edited the import statement check with those once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208210/discussion-between-mahak-malik-and-wwii).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `math.ceil` on the division of 15 of minutes:

```
import math
mint = math.ceil(mint / 15) * 15
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
(math.ceil(mint / 15) * 15) % 60
```

You will need to handle cases where you're rounding up to the next hour.